# [Closed for the moment]Python class definition is not defined. Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-defined-functions, container-classes

I am programming on my phone. I've created the class character to hold all the information about the character such as the Hp.

After defining the hp, I make a function called getHp() which returns the hp.
Later when I call "getHp()" in my "stats()" function it says that "getHp()" is not defined. It does the same for all my functions in my class.
Just fyi "stats()" is just a function  to gather all my variables (within the class) and print them.

```
#Adventure game
import random, time

#===========================#
class character():
      self.xp = 0
    def getLvl(self, xp):
            if xp < 5:
                  level = 1
            elif xp < 20:
                  level = 2
            elif xp < 60:
                  level = 3
            elif xp < 120:
                  level = 4
            else:
                  level = 5
            return level
          self.level = getLvl(self, xp)
#-----------------------------------------#
      self.inventory = {"knife": 1 , "bread": 2 , "gold": 10}

      self.armor = 0
#-----------------------------------------#
      self.attack = 6
      def getAttack(self, attack):
            return attack
#-----------------------------------------#
      self.dmg = 1
      def getDmg(self, dmg):
            return dmg
#-----------------------------------------#
      self.hp = 10 * level + armor
      def getHp(self, hp):
            return hp
      def updateHp(self, playerHp):
            self.hp = playerHp
#-----------------------------------------#
      def stats(self):
            self.getLvl(xp)
            self.getHp(hp)
            self.getAttack(attack)
            self.getDmg(dmg)
            print("Player: \n")
            print("Hp: ", hp, "\nLvl: ", level, "\nAttack: ", attack, "\nDmg: ", dmg)
            print("Inventory: ", self.inventory)
#===========================#

character.stats()
```

Comment: this code is very poorly formatted its hard to say exactly what's wrong

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite I understand, I'll try to fix my code and if I still have the problem I'll come back with my new code.

Answer (score 2):

When you are calling the functions within the class, are you using "self"? In your stats() method it should look like this:

```
def stats(self):
    self.getHp()
```

This is a way that python knows to refer to the getHp() within the class.

You can find more on Classes and self in the python documentations

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: just saw the code that you updated, you are missing the 'self' in function calls, function parameters, and variables as well. Add those in and you'll be good

Comment: I'm guessing I would need an "init" function as well?

Comment: __init__ is a special function that gets executed when you instantiate the object. So if you include an __init__ in your character class, whenever you instantiate a character() object, the __init__ is executed.

Comment: say you def init and have it print('hello'), then later on you instantiate your character class c1 = character(), c2 = character(), 'hello' is printed out twice

Comment: Ah ok and I have added in the "self"s but it still isn't working? I'll update the question with the new code.

Comment: You have to instatiate a character() object before you can call it’s methods. So try doing c1 = character(), then call c1.stats()

Comment: "Self is not defined"

Comment: I've tried that just now and it still says "self is not defined" and I also added self to "class character(self):" and still nothing

Comment: Try class character: you don’t need the () after character

Comment: No, it still came up with the same thing: "self is not defined"

Comment: Could it be that my app needs me to add some sort of module to get self to work?

Comment: hey i ran your code on an IDE, and there are several mistakes that prevented the code from running. 1. the indentation of your code, they matter as thats how python separates code blocks. 2. where you initialize the variables, if it is within the class but not within any methods, you don't need self. I suggest reading up on variable scoping. I also suggest starting off small, create an empty class and have 1 method and 1 variable. Play with the scoping of that variable to understand it better, then create more methods.

Comment: Yeah I know about the indentation, I had to change it around a little bit for it to look normal in the thread above. And for the variables I did a bit of research on "self" and it told me about "_init_" and I saw something about var scoping so I will read up on that a bit more. Thanks a lot for the help though, you were very helpful and I will definitely start again like you said only 1 method.